# What do I call a coat that is light-weighted and usually worn in spring and autumn?

Tags: word-request

What do I call a coat that's light-weighted, usually worn in spring and autumn. The coat extends just above the knee or a little over the knee.

The terms come to my mind are - Dust coat? Over coat? Top coat or spring coat

Comment: Thanks for correcting those mistakes, Maulik, the question looks much better now. I will write whole sentences which are at least grammatically correct next time I ask a question. @Maulik V

Comment: hhmm...I searched some of the terms I know but then did not find the suitable one. Maybe, the best way to describe it is *a short coat* because most of the coats are **of or below knee-length**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S. the adjectives *spring, fall,* or *lightweight* coat could be used.

In some contexts (such as fashion), there might be a difference between a spring coat and a fall coat. A spring coat might be a lighter color, for instance.

In everyday conversation, though, they function pretty much the same, and the terms might be used interchangeably. A fashion diva might pooh-pooh you for calling a dark-colored coat a *spring coat*, but I'd guess most co-workers wouldn't, particularly in a context like:

> *I'm glad the temperatures have finally warmed up! I finally got to take this spring coat off the coat rack*.

By the way, I just did a quick test on Google images, by typing in [spring coat](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1336&bih=874&q=spring%20coat&oq=spring%20coat) and [fall coat](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1336&bih=874&q=fall%20coat&oq=fall%20coat), respectively. As I suspected, both results showed many coats that match the description given by the O.P., but the spring coat results tended to show lighter-colored jackets.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried searching all the terms (yours as well as the terms I know) but could not find the exact term. In my search, I observed that most coats extend **up to or below knees** or else if they are up to waist, they are most likely to be called **jackets**.

I feel the simplest term, without any ambiguity, is a *short coat*. Since you are referring to particular seasons, it might be *a short spring/winter coat*.

Comment: Funny how you mention winter! My first instinct was to think, "No, that's not a winter coat!" but then I realized that this could be very dependent on local climate – one area's winter weather is another location's spring/fall weather. The right seasonal term might very well depend on which season is most likely to see, say, 10°C (50°F) weather.

Comment: Spring and autumn are two distinct seasons that the OP asks. Since winter coat is too common term, I thought to include it. I meant since the OP is referring to a particular season, *a short [the season] coat.*

Comment: In many parts of the U.S., a winter coat tends to be much heavier, to protect against the colder weather. The O.P. specifically asks about a "light-weighted" coat, so that would rule out "winter" as the season, unless perhaps that particular area had a very mild winter.